# merging two data series in a multi-index dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a nested dictionary (three levels) that contain a tuple in the lowest level. The information in the dictionary should be placed in a predefined Index for a multi index DataFrame (two levels) that is imported elsewhere.

The tuple is to be split over the third level of the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

# This is the dataframe template:
index_struct = [('A', 'buffer', 'mean'), ('A', 'buffer', 'var'), ('A', 'cycle', 'mean'), ('A', 'cycle', 'var')
    , ('B', 'buffer', 'mean'), ('B', 'buffer', 'var'), ('B', 'cycle', 'mean'), ('B', 'cycle', 'var')]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index_struct)

# This is the nested dictionary that is passed:
data_dict = {'A': {'buffer': (5, 7)}, 'B': {'buffer': (6, 2), 'cycle': (8, 3)}}
```

A simple `from_dict` on the data yields:

```
print(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data))

[OUT]:

             A       B
buffer  (5, 7)  (6, 2)
cycle      NaN  (8, 3)
```

`print(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')` calculates the same.

Whereas I would like it to look like this:

```
       A                     B                
  buffer      cycle     buffer      cycle     
    mean  var  mean var   mean  var  mean  var
0    5.0  7.0   NaN NaN    6.0  2.0   8.0  3.0
```

Presumably the solution should contain two steps:
Adding the mean-var information to the data and then implementing it into the DataFrame template.

I am a bit lost in the may options that the pandas package provides. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can re-create the DataFrame after reading it to split the tuples. Then this is `.reindex`, after ensuring things are ordered properly (with `swaplevel`).

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict).stack()

df = (pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), columns=['mean', 'var'], index=s.index).stack()
        .swaplevel(0, 1)
        .reindex(index)
        .to_frame()
        .T)
```

---

```
       A                     B                
  buffer      cycle     buffer      cycle     
    mean  var  mean var   mean  var  mean  var
0    5.0  7.0   NaN NaN    6.0  2.0   8.0  3.0
```

Comment: This indeed works in the "minor" problem, however when I implement it in the main project (where ```index_struct```template is a lot longer (same three levels, btw)) the ```reindex(index)``` returns an empty DataFrame. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: @LFSvenne empty, or all rows are filled with `NaN`?

Comment: Empty dataframe. The index value is ```[0]``` column value is ```[]```. When I export to csv the tuples of the original indices are printed in the rows and an extra 0 after the last row.

Comment: @LFSvenne double check what `index` is just before the code. Seems like it may have been overwritten to None or something if there are no columns. If it's a list of tuples you should be getting those columns.

Comment: Ok, the "template" index originated from a csv file which was read with a .from_frame command. Transposing data in the .csv file resulted in the desired columns. Not very elegant, but does the trick.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would resolve your issue, but if you write your data as

```
data_dict =  {('A', 'buffer', 'mean'): 5, 
              ('A', 'buffer', 'var'): 7, 
              ('A', 'cycle', 'mean'): np.nan,
              ('A', 'cycle', 'var'): np.nan, 
              ('B', 'buffer', 'mean'): 6, 
              ('B', 'buffer', 'var'): 2, 
              ('B', 'cycle', 'mean'): 8, 
              ('B', 'cycle', 'var'): 3}
```

then

```
pd.Series(data_dict).to_frame().T
```

would lead to desired output.

Comment: It is the shuffle that you describe that I was trying to find, but could not figure it out.